# Need a setter on a JPA/Hibernate entity for an ID AND a foreign entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two entities with a many-to-one relationship between them. Many B entities are related to an A entity. My B table has an `A_ID` column. In some situations, we may have a B entity that has an `A_ID` but doesn't relate to any row in A. I know this isn't ideal but it's part of the old system and we can't really touch this portion of the code.

With proper Hibernate entities, I'm able to add B entities when we have an A entity to associate with using B's `setA()` method and B's `getAs().add()` method. I don't see any way to deal with the case where I'd like to add a B entity that isn't associated with an A entity (B's `A_ID = 10`, for example, where there's no A with an `ID = 10`). Is this possible or am I stuck breaking our entity hierarchy at this point and dealing with it manually?

Is there some way to add a `setAId()` to the B entity and either use that or the `setA()` method but not both? Will Hibernate allow this? When I try to add the getter and setter on B, I get the following error:

```
MyHibernateException: Hibernate SessionFactory creation failed, hibernateCfgFileNm=hibernate.xml
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: test.B column: A_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Sorry for not providing code. I think this explanation is sufficient but if code is required, I can add it.

Answer (score 1):

With my understanding of entity relations (I assume you're mapping these with standard JPA `@ManyToOne` / `@OneToMany` relations?) I believe you're going to run into some fun issues here.

I would create my A entities using a sequence generated ID, and allow for 'placeholder' A entities which do nothing but carry the A_ID from the old system. Just make your code aware that not every A entity will be a full entity (it may just place-hold those A_IDs you mentioned above) and gracefully handle it, allowing you to always provide an A entity, with an ID decoupled from the legacy system.

I don't think you'll be able to map the relation to the same column and set a value in the column without the relation causing issues -- unless perhaps if you mark the relation as `LAZY` fetch and catch the exceptions which are bound to occur when it tries to resolve the non-existent Entity A. That may also work -- in that case, try to map the relationship column as read-only (`insert="false"` `update="false"`), and do everything with the `setAId(id)`. You may need to have your `setA(A)` method only operate on IDs rather than managed collections, since reading a collection will by it's very nature fetch any related rows.

Your best bet is to decouple from the IDs of the legacy system if the semantics of the legacy IDs loosely translate to 'here, this ID may be a null object.'